# Is there a text qualifier for logical operators?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm counting the number of each entry in a given column. The `COUNTIF` is pretty straight-forward:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,A1)
```

However, `<empty>` was used at some point to designate empty cells. I was surprised to find that the count for these cells was not the number of cells that said `<empty>`, but instead was apparently the number of cells that alphabetically come before "empty>". Excel was treating the leading "<" as a logical operator.

Is there a way to tell Excel to ignore the logical operator and just view it as text?

Here's some sample data that exhibits the same result:

```
+----+-----------------------+---+
|    |           A           | B |
+----+-----------------------+---+
|  1 | Lorem ipsum dolor sit | 1 |
|  2 | Sed ultricies enim    | 1 |
|  3 | <empty>               | 5 |
|  4 | Donec mollis velit at | 1 |
|  5 | <empty>               | 5 |
|  6 | Nam in nisl at tortor | 1 |
|  7 | Duis mattis ex sit    | 1 |
|  8 | Phasellus             | 1 |
|  9 | <empty>               | 5 |
| 10 | Etiam at              | 1 |
+----+-----------------------+---+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an easy workaround:

```
=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,"="&A1)
```

Certain special characters (e.g. `*` and `?`) can be escaped using the tilde `~`, but the above is appropriate for this setup.

[image]

Comment: Baah, too slow.

Comment: Lol literally the same time.

Comment: Workaround does the job perfectly. Thanks! But just to fully understand fully: the tilde results in a count of 0 when I use it thusly: `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$10,"~<empty>")`. Am I mis-using it?

Comment: Hmm - so the tilde doesn't escape `<`. It does escape the special characters `*` and `?`. I should have tested further.

Comment: I should've mentioned that as part of my research in the initial question. Is it that `*` and `?` don't count as logical operators and are wildcards instead? Just spitballin' here...

Comment: Yes that is correct. Logical operators will come at the beginning of the criterion; `*` and `?` can come anywhere. In the workaround, `=` becomes the logical operator and so the `<` is treated as text.